# ggplot2 bar chart rename legend labels with ggplotly()

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, legend

I have a bar chart with `states` on x-axis, `counts` on y-axis and fill with 3 different `years` (`2020`, `2019`, `2018`).

I want to rename the fill legend labels to following: `This Year`, `Last Year`, `2 Years Ago`.

I tried to use `scale_fill_discrete` but failed. Only change the legend title:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x = states, y = counts)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = years), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
    scale_fill_discrete(name = "New Title", labels = c("This Year", "Last Year", "2 Years Ago"))
```

Do I miss anything here?

**UPDATE**
After plot with `ggplot`, I used `ggplotly` to make it be interactive. I think the problems came from `ggplotly`.

Comment: Are your years numeric? If so, change them to character or factor.

Comment: I think the problem came from `ggplotly()`. I edited the question.

Comment: Looks like a bug in `ggplotly()`. As a workaround you can add a column with the labels and map this column on the `fill` aes.